# Link not firing to PHP in IE

Tags: php, html, header

I have a href tag linking to a php page where I can download a file dynamically from what the user clicked.

The download works on Chrome and Firefox, but not Internet Explorer.

Here is my tag.

```
<p class='order-item-list'><a href='singleDownload.php?download=".$x['id']."&type=".$x['fileType']."' target='_blank'><input id='downloadSingle' type='image' src='images/download-single.png' alt='Submit' value='download' /></a></p>
```

I have it enclosed the p tag for styling purposes.

I've tried going directly to the file with the inputted GET parameters and it works on IE. Just the link is not firing for whatever reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/), your HTML has errors in it.

If you want a link containing an image, then use a `<a>` containing an `<img>`.

If you want a server side image map then use a `<input type="image">` and don't use an `<a>`.

Comment: But it would break my nice single line comment!

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! I forgot about the validator. I don't know why that was an input tag, anyways it is all fixed.